# Exodus exported private key

Tags: address-generation, bitcore, private-key-export, exodus

I'm trying to understand why I'm having a hard time at importing exodus private keys in other wallets like jaxx o scatter.

I can't understand why I don't get the public address from the private key with this script:

```
var bitcore = require("bitcore-lib")
var privateKey = bitcore.PrivateKey.fromString("**** exodus private key ****")
console.log(privateKey.toAddress().toString())
```

I'm not able either to get the address from the seed phrase by using https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ indicating bip32 derivation path to m/0/0.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably deriving a legacy P2PKH address (addresses that start with 1) versus the bech32 P2WPKH address (addresses that start with bc1) that Exodus uses.

A single WIF private key can generate multiple address types, other wallets and software are likely defaulting to a different type which is probably why you are having trouble. This is the same for seed phrases as well.

Also just FYI Bitcore-lib is an old outdated library and is not compatible with modern address types. The code example you provide would create a legacy P2PKH address (start with 1).